# Rosencrantz and Guildenstern are Code

Tags: code-golf

In the absurdist play *[Rosencrantz and Guildenstern are Dead](https://d3jc3ahdjad7x7.cloudfront.net/HgjKbM59FD5bFo4Khi3czmVu0dUiw1Pru7Lya3BKNaDtfvrn.pdf)*, the two main characters **Rosencrantz** and **Guildenstern**(or are they?) are always mixing up which of them is who—or sometimes which of their own body parts is which—because of a perceived lack of individual identity. Wouldn't it be absurd if they even shuffled around their names?

Your task it to write a function which takes in a string of an **even** length(and by design, a multiple of 4) that is greater than 7 characters, split it, and shuffle it.

*The splitting shall be as follows*:
the string will be of format `"abscd"`, with s acting as a seperator character. The first section and the separator, `abs` will be the first half of the string, whereas the second half will be `cd`

The length of `a` will be `(string length / 4) - 1`

The length of `b` will be `(string length / 4)`

The length of `s` will be `1`

The length of `c` will be `(string length / 4) + 1`

The length of `d` will be `(string length / 4) - 1`

This may be really confusing, so let me show you
with some examples

```
("a" + "bb" + "s" + "ccc" + "d").length //8
  1     2      1      3      1
|-------4--------|  |----4-----| <--- (4 is half of 8)

("rosen" + "crantz" + "&" + "guilden" + "stern").length  //24
    5         6        1        7          5

("foo" + "barr" + "?" + "barry" + "foo").length
   3       4       1      5         3
```

**Finally:**

You then shuffle the parts around, outputting `adscb`

ex. `"rosencrantz&guildenstern" --> "rosenstern&guildencrantz"`

`"foobarr?barryfoo" --> "foofoo?barrybarr"`

## Rulez:

1. [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are prohibited
2. Acceptable answers: a function which takes input through one input string and returns one output string
3. If the input string doesn't match the requirements provided above,
   your code MUST error out(doesn't matter what kind of `Exception` or
   `Error`)
4. This is `code-golf`, so the shortest(valid)answer (in each language)
   wins!
5. **Bonus points for a one-liner** :-) (Not really tho, just cool points)

Comment: Regarding your gangsta rulez: It is generally discouraged to favour _"functions"_, as they are hard to define in general. Furthermore, handling invalid input is also mostly avoided, as it usually boils down to annoying boiler-plate code.

Comment: @JonathanFrech I think the challenge of input validation is an interesting problem, as it can be handled a variety of ways from array traversal, to branching logic, to RegEx testing, so optimization of these can add a extra challenge ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I'll try that for another code golf challenge though :-)

Comment: tfw everyone is trying to get more flexible io methods to make the code in their favorite golfing lang. and tfw it happens on almost all questions

Comment: [Things to Avoid when writing challenges (Input Validation)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16596/76162).

Comment: @JoKing thanks for spotting that!

Comment: I'd recommend a test case of length 4 since every answer didn't handle that

Comment: @JoKing the spec indicates "greater than 7 characters"

Comment: @NathanMerrill And? The first 3 answers didn't handle it correctly, though mine and the `K` answer have both fixed that since posting.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand here: "length 4" is not "greater than 7 characters". Why do you think that answers have to handle it?

Comment: @NathanMerrill It's mentioned in the spec that input has to be greater than 7 characters in length and its length must be divisible by four, Jo King was suggesting a test case entry of length 4 such "abcd" which should error out

Comment: Ah, I understand.  Answers still have to handle it by erroring. :)

Comment: Is erroring necessary in languages where catching errors is non-trivial (and thus an error will crash the program), or is it enough to simply produce an output indicating an error, i.e. a null-pointer or empty string?

Answer (score 11):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s><sub>35</sub></s> <s><sub>34</sub></s> 33 bytes

```
{$[8>#x;.;<x!4!-&4#-1 0 2+-4!#x]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWiXawk65wlrP2qZC0URRV81EWddQwUDBSFvXRFG5Irb2f4KBlU6aglJiUlJxcnJyihIXTAAoAhZKTkEIFuUXp@YlFyXmlVSppZdm5qSk5hWXpBblwRWk5ecnJRYV2YOISiAHybicYiDKTslKy0ksTslOVPoPAA)

## Without input validation (for ngn's bounty), <s><sub>25</sub></s> <s><sub>24</sub></s> 23 bytes

```
{<x!4!-&4#-1 0 2+-4!#x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82q2qZC0URRV81EWddQwUDBSFvXRFG5ovZ/goGVTpqCUmJSUnFycnKKEhdMACgCFkpOQQgW5Ren5iUXJeaVVKmll2bmpKTmFZekFuXBFaTl5yclFhXZg4hKIAdhXBLIbC6gO1SiLeyUK6wN1a3RXaShXKGpahJby4XTTcU5KWnZWYnFKdlpWYk5xdkpQErpPwA)

Quickly learned a bit of K and, looking at the list of verbs, I thought an alternative approach (*not* using cut) could work here. And it worked perfectly.

#### How it works

```
{<x!4!-&4#-1 0 2+-4!#x}
                 -4!#x    Length divided by four (floor division)
        4#-1 0 2+         Generate lengths (x/4-1, x/4, x/4+2, x/4-1)
       &                  Generate that many 0, 1, 2, 3's
    4!-                   Negate and modulo 4; effectively swap 1 and 3
 <x!                      Sort the original string by above

{$[8>#x;.; <code> ]}  Input validation
 $[8>#x           ]   If the length is less than 8
        .             Dynamically generate an error
           <code>     Otherwise, run the main code
```

Comment: @ngn What happened to my eyes O.o

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>103</strike> <strike>102</strike> <strike>101</strike> <strike>97</strike> <strike>88</strike> <strike>86</strike> 84 bytes

```python
def f(s):l=len(s);l//=4*(l%4<1<l/4);return s[:l-1]+s[1-l:]+s[2*l-1:1-l]+s[l-1:2*l-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lUxLDoIwEN1zikqifAwhKKsCcaOXkLBAGLRJMyXTYsTLIzUGVy6cxcz7zetHc1O4n6YWOtb5OuCykIAzyGQcF2noy3WaJ7mM0yAjMAMh0yWXUVJtdZlEktu7C2eBz8wSC99CNfUk0Pid75LSgA3VaJ6b6yBkC6gNELpB4CyhTqlLTXSwa5yJNR1DI3cYW0JAn7EuPBroDTsDqaO4Cy0UnogUfT@8N195P5r@LJle)

Not really a one-liner, but `;` is one less byte per line than linebreak and indent.

Throws `ZeroDivisionError` if input string length is less than 8 or not an integer multiple of 4.

Also works in Python 2.

<sub>-4 bytes thanks to Jo King</sub>

<sub>-9 bytes thanks to ovs</sub>

<sub>-2 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech</sub>

<sub>-2 bytes thanks to Bubbler</sub>

Comment: @JoKing thanks for the tips, much appreciated :)

Comment: [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYpBCsIwEEX3nqIUlCSllGpBSK0epHRR7UQLw6RM0kW9fExcCG6G996fZfMvS6cQJjCZEU5q7BAoQotV1TVKCNw3l1oqvJ5ly@BXpsz1Gst6KFxfYlHrBEcVi06aLPG3DGHhmbwwImfrgB48kn8fnuuME5DzwJRLufs9GWvvI/MtnS3K3wjMlmMJHw)

Comment: @ovs nice catch on the adjacent indexes, as for the parens, I tried around for at least 20 minutes to see if I could get rid of some of them, then I completely missed that with the change to `//=` the outermost pair became redundant. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `-l+1` <-> `1-l`?

Comment: Merge the two inequalities to get to [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##dYvNDoIwDMfvPgWSKBuGEJTTgHjyKQgHhKIkS0e6kYgvPzdDOGkP7f/j12kxT4UXa3sYgoFpLmQlAZ0oZJpWeczkIS@zUqY5LwjMTBjoWsgka066zhIp/D3HLhDOeePlN2jsRCMaNrCQlAbsqEXzPj7mUfaA2gBhyPlugwal7i3R1a/FGV8aWsQGAK3jG3h1MJm1jG5EivbRj4f/rP0A).

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>60</s> 58 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Jo King*

```perl6
{[~] .rotor($_/4 X-1,0,+^-$_+>2,-1,1)[0,4,2,3,1;*]}o*.comb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY67DoIwFIbn8hRnIESxIEW8BS8xLu46mBglKK0xAWoOdUCDr44FBx3@y3fyD@fOMR3VWQmWgHn9OryP4KJUEjtm1A9g7zDq0d7JMaPewqeaWPfg0YD6dEBZaB8rabsXmZ3r0BASYYay4PkF41w9revjliY8LxTHHISU5xhx2VipAZg/CFobjsaT6a95f5Ut4GUQhWUTpIhLEPqvbqhhvdqtN@2ZJFzEj1R9gbhbha6eNiNSGa0qo6o/)

Throws "Rotorizing sublist length is out of range" in case of error.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{               # Anonymous block
 [~]            # Join
   .rotor(      # Split into sublists of specific length
     $_/4 X-    # Subtract from len/4
     1,
     0,
     +^-$_+>2,  # (len-1)>>2
                #   subtraction yields 1 if len is multiple of 4
                #   otherwise a value less than 1 causing an error
     -1,       
     1)
   [0,4,2,3,1;*]  # Rearrange sublists and take inner elements
}o*.comb          # Split into characters and feed into block
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s><sub>36</sub></s> 35 bytes

```
5;@A.](<;.2~;)1<@{."+~1 0 _2 1-4%~#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxLCsIwGIT3nuKnorGowRbdNBXrQUTyLBVJIKkLFXP1mCbQxQzzzcA8QoEBKTg3CHbwa@AAUeFEuiu@bVqCa0/Kqu2@uNj6Kq73Gqr9ceWXoQwKEGXMcc4FWkwQKSEXubDGSc0t1eNn3b@Gp5DajdLqNCpjGLX2Mtk7Qr5gXEjVzzmFTE5RJ2ahPw)

-1 byte by `{.` + negative lengths & `;.2` which cuts on ones as "ending" markers instead.

### Original answer, 36 bytes

```
5;@A.](<;.1~;)1<@{."+~_1 0 2 _1+4%~#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxLCsIwGIT3nuKnorFUgpG6aSrWg0jJsyiSQFIXKubqMW2gixnmm4F5xAID0nBuEOzh18ABkuKJdld827UUk0BL0nZfXFShJ2k@Qk@qehPWsYwaEOPcCyEkWk2QaEYhc@GsV0Y4ZsbPdnjdn1IZPypn5lFby5lzl8neCfIFF1LpYclzyOQ183IR@gM)

ngn mentioned "cut" on a comment to an [earlier K answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175208/78410), and it made me try J which has the same "cut" (I have no idea how K works).

#### How it works

```
5;@A.](<;.1~;)1<@{."+~_1 0 2 _1+4%~#  Monadic train.
                                4%~#  Length divided by four
                      _1 0 2 _1+      Generate the four segment lengths
              1<@{."+~  Generate [1 0 0...] boxed arrays of those lengths
      (     ;)          Raze; unbox and concatenate
     ] <;.1~            Cut the input string on ones as starting marker, then box each
5  A.  Rearrange the boxes in the order 0 3 2 1
 ;@    Raze again
```

Note that this function automatically handles invalid inputs:

- If the input length is not a multiple of four, `{.` throws `domain error` since its length argument has to be integers.
- If the input length is 4, the cut produces only two segments, and `5 A.` throws `index error`.
- If the input length is 0, the two arguments to cut don't have the same length, so `length error` is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <strike>120</strike> <strike>113</strike> <strike>103</strike> <strike>99</strike> 95 bytes

```
{$[(r>7)&0=4!r:#:x;{g:(s:*|(y*2)#x)\x;((y-1)#*g),((-y-1)#*|g),s,((y+1)#*|g),(-y)#*g}[x;r%4];l]}
```

Hopefully can be golfed down more, included an extra function for testing if string length is divisible by four, outputs error with reference to undeclared variable if input is invalid

EDIT: Missed condition on length greater than 7, included

EDIT: Combined into one function, removed redundant variable declarations

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrNCsIwEATgu29hqmUTLagUhAT1QWoP/TOIJYHdColtnz2miJdhPmZemdEmBJLjpgC8nnl6uORrlIl0atQSSIoJvDjxxPG7UwA@O/JEaL4HyH59iqBIv/srLstnLpzCbV6qvpwDsYe1dYV4W8JHsBUxtNSZBiszfFL9fvZtZ2jo0CxbVTctC18)

Comment: this could be a lot shorter. do you know about "cut" (`indices_string`)? ping me in [the orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) if i should explain it

Comment: i can do it in 34 bytes :)

Comment: I know about cut, but I didn't think about using it... 34 bytes?! 
I'm going to have to give this another go when I get home and see if I get near that

Comment: i should mention: my solution doesn't make sure that invalid inputs (length<=7) cause an error

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 78 bytes

```perl6
*.comb[0..*/4-2,3* */4+1..*,*/2-1/(*>7)..3* */4,*/4-1/(*%%4)..*/2-2].flat.join
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtLDsIgGIT3noKQtClYfoQ2ujDqQYwLWqGpacFAXdTLI0TjZjKPb57aT/s4r6g06IQihd7N3XUHQHnLZN1QlMxWpFxTLpngFT0fCMB3qDOVu6JoSf5IJm9gJrXAw402HjdBrchU2Lugbe@VXd7l8Bqnu7Zh0d5i8kMQNs51yvtLljUF/F@EbFocPw)

Anonymous code block that takes a string and returns the modified string if valid, else returns a division by zero error. I know I can modify an array directly, so I could swap the two sections of the string, but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64 bytes

```ruby
->s{a=s.size/4;s[1-a,a],s[a-1,a]=s[a-1,a],s[1-a,a];s[a*4]?1/0:s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664OtG2WK84sypV38S6ONpQN1EnMVanODpR1xDIsIUxdGBSQDWJWiax9ob6BlbFtf8LSkuKFdKilYryi1PzkosS80qq1NJLM3NSUvOKS1KL8pRiuWBK0vLzkxKLiuxBRCWQgyTll1qWWuSen5eX6J5ZlhqZXxpaoBT7HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-Dx=memcpy` and `-DL=(l-1)`, <strike>154</strike> <strike>158</strike> 160 bytes

Returns NULL if the input string length is not divisible by 4 or shorter than 8 characters.

Thanks to Rogem and Jonathan Frech for the suggestions.

EDIT: Moved preprocessor defines to the command line and made the string dynamically-allocated to strictly conform with the puzzle.

```c
f(s,t,l)char*s,*t;{l=strlen(s);l%4|l<8?t=0:(t=malloc(l+1),l/=4,x(t,s,L),x(t+L,s+3*l+1,L),x(t+2*L,s+L+l,l+2),x(t+3*l,s+L,l),t[4*l]=0);l=t;}//-Dx=memcpy -DL=(l-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/JbgIxDIbvPEWERJVtxFIOVYeUC8d5A8ohZJZG8mRQnFIo5dWbJl3oxf79/ZYXU3TGxNhSlEECMy/ac5Q8lBdQGDw0jiIrYbL8gNXDOqjZIw2q1wCDoSDmTMJULeWJBomyYlmISqK458n8AwueUSVAglj8oORnlDbKsF1y2KlZ2qJCeZ1Oi81J9U1vDmdSbCpFoZizaF0gvbaOZqF9ZyTJtxLOU3Fk5DIipB38t23VvCR2lbtSFoKRg0@8peMJEvVEJvjsxjJPOW7tTpKW/krGytE1Rr3fozGmjn7AxhmvXXi/614t1I3D0HgX22HYa@/XOZxTEbEfIN141GDrT9OC7jAWb/H/lXh75Qs)

Comment: Why `t[80]`? There does not seem to be an upper bound regarding input length.

Comment: @JonathanFrech I did it to save bytes but you are correct. I've changed the solution to use `malloc()` instead.

Comment: Returns by modification, return value is `NULL` for invalid output, uses return values from `memcpy()`, a function-like macro to skip the types and C99 variable-length arrays to skip `malloc()`.

Comment: Why 160 bytes, do you count the `//` or the `-w`?

Comment: @l4m2 `-w` is just a convenience to suppress warnings (so errors are easier to find). I usually add command line arguments after a `//` to have TIO count their bytes for me, and then deduct 1 from the total to account for the one extra character needed to do that.

Comment: @ceilingcat I've posted as a competing solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 58 or 73 or 83 or 93 bytes

```
((((.)))*?)(.(?<-2>.)+)(...(?<-3>.)+)((?<-4>.)+)$
$1$7$6$5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fAwj0NDU1tew1NfQ07G10jez0NLWBbD0wzxjCAzFNwEwVLhVDFXMVMxXT//@L8otT85KLEvNKqtTSSzNzUlLziktSi/IA) Explanation:

```
((((.)))*?)
```

Capture `a` in `$1`, and make it as short as possible `*?`. `$#2`, `$#3` and `$#4` end up as the length of `a`.

```
(.(?<-2>.)+)
```

Capture `b` in `$4`. The `(?<-2>.)+` captures up to the length of `a`, while the other `.` adds 1 to its length as required.

```
(...(?<-3>.)+)
```

Capture `s` and `c` in `$6`. Their combined length is three more than the length of `a`.

```
((?<-4>.)+)
```

Capture `d` in `$7`. Its length is no more than the length of `a`.

```
$
```

We made `a` as short as possible, but we still want to reach the end of the input.

```
$1$7$6$5
```

Exchange `b` and `d`.

The above stage does not validate its input. As Retina has no run-time errors, there are a number of options for input validation:

```
G`^(....){2,}$
```

Outputs nothing if the length is less than 8 or not a multiple of 4. (+15 bytes)

```
^(?!(....){2,}$).*
Error
```

Outputs `Error` if the length is less than 8 or not a multiple of 4. (+25 bytes)

```
+`^(....)*..?.?$|^(....)?$
.....$1
```

Hangs if the length is less than 8 or not a multiple of 4. (+35 bytes)

Comment: This doesn't throw an error on invalid inputs (as annoying as that is)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>97</s> 89 bytes

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to @l4m2*

```javascript
s=>(l=s.length/4)<2||l%1?Z:s.replace(eval(`/(.{${l}})(.{${l+2}})(.{${l-1}})$/`),'$3$2$1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcpBDoIwEIXhvccgVdooJaArI3IPV9QyIGbSIW0lUeDsFWPiws3L95L/rgbltO16nxiqITRFcMWZY@Ekgmn9LT2IUz5NuM7Ky9FJCz0qDRwGhbxKuRzZiPMsvtjmPybZQpZWYhezPctZFougyThCkEgtb3hkyYHRVhn/2rSPDmswzoM1kRCrv7Qhuipry888l7Mk4Q0)

Comment: [89B](https://tio.run/##XcpBDoIwEIXhvccgVdooJaArI3IPV9QyIGbSIW0lUeDsFWPiws3L95L/rgbltO16nxiqITRFcMWZY@Ekgmn9LT2IUz5NuM7Ky9FJCz0qDRwGhbxKuRzZiPMsvtjmPybZQpZWYhezPctZFougyThCkEgtb3hkyYHRVhn/2rSPDmswzoM1kRCrv7Qhuipry888l7Mk4Q0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 28 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
L7»4ḍİ×L:4;;ĖÄƲFÄœṖ⁸⁽%[D¤ị$F
```

(If a full program is allowed we can remove the trailing `F`)
If the length is less than 8 or not divisible by four a `ValueError` is raised during integer division of `inf` (a float) by `4` -- the division yields `NaN` (also a float) which then cannot be cast to an `int`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVMArP9qZWxsef//TDfCuzThuI3EsMOXTDo0OzvElsOExrJGw4TFk@G5luKBuOKBvSVbRMKk4buLJEb///8icm9zZW5jcmFudHomZ3VpbGRlbnN0ZXJuIg)**

#### How?

```
L7»4ḍİ×L:4;;ĖÄƲFÄœṖ⁸⁽%[D¤ị$F - Link: list of characters
L                            - length
 7                           - literal seven
  »                          - maximum (of length & 7)
   4ḍ                        - divisible by four? (yields 1 for good inputs; 0 otherwise)
     İ                       - inverse (1 yields 1; 0 yields inf)
      ×L                     - multiply by length (length or inf)
        :4                   - integer divide by 4 (errors given inf)
              Ʋ              - last four links as a monad (f(x)):
          ;                  -   concatenate -> [x,x]
            Ė                -   enumerate -> [1,x]
           ;                 -   concatenate -> [x,x,[1,x]]
             Ä               -   cumulative sum (vectorises at depth 1) -> [x,x,[1,1+x]]
               F             - flatten -> [x,x,1,1+x]
                Ä            - cumulative sum -> [x,2x,2x+1,3x+2]
                   ⁸         - chain's left argument (the input)
                 œṖ          - partition at indices (chops up as per requirements)
                          $  - last two links as a monad (f(z)):
                        ¤    -   nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                    ⁽%[      -     10342
                       D     -     decimal digits -> [1,0,3,4,2]
                         ị   -   index into z (rearranges the pieces as per requirements)
                           F - flatten (back to a list of characters)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
L:4’+“¡¢¢£¡‘Ṡ3¦ÄṬk⁸Ṛ2,5¦Ẏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVMArP9qZWxsef//TDo04oCZK@KAnMKhwqLCosKjwqHigJjhuaAzwqbDhOG5rGvigbjhuZoyLDXCpuG6jv///3Jvc2VuY3JhbnR6Jmd1aWxkZW5zdGVybg)

The `Ẏ` can be removed to make this into a full program.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 80 bytes

```javascript
s=>(g=s.substr.bind(s))(0,l=s.length/4-1)+g(-l)+g(l-~l,l+3)+g(l,l+1,l<1==l%1||Z)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYpBCsIwEEX3HqOgJLSpBl0avYe7tE1jZZiRmVRQilePrUtx83j/8W/@4aXl4Z4MUhdy77K4k4pOahkbSVw3A3ZKtFa7CuYKAWO6bg/G6jIqAwvBvKGCcv/1WWwFR@scrO00XXRuCYUg1EBR9apgkoAte0yvTRwH6AJKCoyF1qufa0/UeObzguc8/lwCM/Hc8wc)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 84 bytes

```javascript
s=>(g=(a,b)=>s.substr(a,b))(0,l=s.length/4-1)+g(-l)+g(l-~l,l+3)+g(l,l+1,l<1==l%1||Z)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYpBCsIwEEX3HqOgJDSpBl2aeg93aZvGypCRmVRQilePbZfi5vHe59/d03FLwyPpiJ3Pvc1saxGscKqRtuaKx4YTrSnFQYHlCnwM6bY/aSPLIDQsBP0BBeVx9VmMgrOxFrZmmq4ytxgZwVeAQfSiIGQfW3IxvXdhHKDzkZOnWEi5@bn2iI0juix4zfHn4omQ5j1/AQ)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 87 bytes

```javascript
s=>(l=s.length/4)<2||l%1?Z:(g=(a,b)=>s.substr(a,b))(0,l-1)+g(1-l)+g(l+l-1,l+2)+g(l-1,l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYrNDoIwEITvPgaJZht@FOLJWHgPbwVKxWy6ZreYaHj3ChyNl5n5Jt/DvIx0PD5D7qm3cdBRdA2opUDrXbgfz@pazTPuy@Z2AafBZK3StRQytRJ4QwWnDPNSpQ7KHNfCdOEM02qDdarYkRdCWyA5GCBhEus7Nj58Dm4asbdegmWfKLX7UQei1jA3a7wX@KNYZuLlj18)

Shorter than RegExp

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 135 bytes

```java
s->{int l=s.length();l=l>7&l%4<1?l/4:l/0;return s.substring(0,l-1)+s.substring(3*l+1)+s.substring(2*l-1,3*l+1)+s.substring(l-1,2*l-1);}
```

Throws `ArithmeticException` (divides by zero) if the input string does not match requirements. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##hY7RSsMwFIavu6cIBUe7remmA8Fu3ROIF8Mr2UXWpjXz7KQkJ4M69uw1XVVEBCGcJN//5ScHcRKJbiQeyreucXtQBStAWMsehUJ2HgWf0JIgv520KtnRR9GWjML6ZceEqW3cm8HBl3FHCnjlsCClkT@jMO1TI40gbVbDm5xVbM06m@RnhcRgbTlIrOk1ijNYQ34/hpvlarGBdPkA6TwzkpxBZrl1e3ttiOYzSBbx9Ce6m8D0F7qdeGv2R9Djaxhnly4IMv/3bWtJHrl2xBvvEGBUcdE00Eah0VZiYQTS@7h2CkqJXjYYxnHG0pQNwhV95YMd/lNcab0Xxmz60frLd6E/@zXwfviiy@jSfQA).

Ungolfed:

```java
s -> { // lambda function taking a String argument and returning a String
    int l = s.length(); // take the length of the input ...
    l = l > 7 &         // ... if it's  greater than 7 and ...
        l % 4 < 1       // ... a multiple of 4 ...
      ? l / 4           // ... divide by 4; otherwise ...
      : l / 0;          // ... error out (division by zero throws ArithmeticException)
    return // concatenate and return:
           s.substring(0, l - 1)             // a
         + s.substring(3 * l + 1)            // d
         + s.substring(2 * l - 1, 3 * l + 1) // sc
         + s.substring(l - 1, 2 * l - 1);    // b
}
```

Comment: Suggest `l/=l>7&l%4<1?4:0;` instead of `l=l>7&l%4<1?l/4:l/0;`

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 129 bytes

Returns by modification.
Compile with:

```
-Df(s)=({char t[l=strlen(s)];l%4|l<8?0:(l/=4,x(t,s+l*2-1,l-~l),x(x(x(s+l*3,s+l-1,l)-l-2,t,l+2)-l+1,t+l+2,l-1),s);}) -Dx=memcpy
```

Source file:

```c
l;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVHNbsIwDL7zFFElpoYkYmUcJkrHhbdgHNKQdpXcFCWBwRh79GVOqQRvMEVy7O/HchwlaqVCgHw6FesqdbRIL@pDWuI3UDhvQRsEtzmM59@wfF09L1KYFnN@Sj13DCYzkXEQP0ARiSdiL5GJOBUgZtxzYDNMWcY9wxT1GeWO5ldKxPpUtLpV@3NojCetbEwaE2lrxUk/yGSCxZGSy4gMQHmociyqzvbapshy0iyjBW/GaFQSEimcnhRkeEZss2m2NO9pbIKU1RKgUylWnDCGsoG@DXXDByMnd3pvsX2VJmNHijcydu8medBV0UdXGBZJ0juucV6rdU/ko2sIsiydUmoXbOe0UVYa//VUHxrYaeO8tiZUXVdKa1cxnLEIru0A13SU0Ox@VQWydkF8hocd/sMX/gE)

### Degolf

```c
-Df(s)=({ // Function-like macro f. Takes a char* as a parameter.
          // Return value is a pointer to s if successful, and to NULL if string was invalid.
     char t[l=strlen(s)]; // Allocate a local temp string.
     l%4|l<8?0: // Detect invalid strings. Return 0 (NULL) on invalid string.
         (l/=4, // We're only really concerned with floor(len/4), and this will yield that.
             memcpy(t,s+l*2-1,l-~l), // Copy the second half of chars to the temp storage.
             memcpy( // Because memcpy returns the address of the destination, we can chain
                     // the calls to save quite a few bytes, even after x->memcpy substitution.
                 memcpy(memcpy(s+l*3,s+l-1,l) // Next, copy the second quarter to the end.
                     -l-2,t,l+2) // After that, we copy back the third quarter to its place.
                          -l+1,t+l+2,l-1) // Finally, copy the fourth quarter to where the second
                                          // quarter was.
                      ,s);}) // And return the pointer.
```